# null on json data

Tags: php

I am trying to parse this json data from the url but i get NULL how do i fix this issue.

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://partners.socialvi.be/e414f702cf3db89a2fe58066bbab369d65b6a058/activities/available.json');

$json = json_decode($source);

var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing the contents of `$source` before you `json_decode()` it all?

Comment: what do you get when you call the url directly before decoding ?

Comment: The URL returns `onSVJson([])` for me, so no wonder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the API returns the data in [JSONP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), not pure JSON. Notice the surrounding `onSVJson([])`. You'll either have to strip this out, or read the API documentation and try another request format. My guess would be that leaving out the final `&callback=onSVJson` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That's because if you call the url (go to http://partners.socialvi.be/e414f702cf3db89a2fe58066bbab369d65b6a058/activities/available.json?network_user_id=3459874&max_activities=9&callback=onSVJson with your browser) the json that is returned has no values

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last part of the URL (`&callback=onSVJson`) and it'll work.

Many APIs offer a feature called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), that allows the JSON to be passed to a callback function, in order to simplify access via cross domain JavaScript. But for PHP you don't need that.

The name of the callback function is typically specified using the `callback` GET parameter. If you leave that out, no callback function is used - just plain JSON.